# Fetch the list of links(url's) from washington post website representing different web pages

Tags: python, web-scraping, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

To get the set of url's by crawling the washington post news website, and get the list of urls of web pages and finally save it to a text file.

here is my code

```
import urllib2
import urllib
from cookielib import CookieJar
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

cj = CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
text_file = "http://www.washingtonpost.com/newssearch/search.html?st=turkey&submit=Submit"
data = opener.open(text_file).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
paragraph = soup.find_all('div', attrs = {'class': 'pb-feed-headline'})
for href in paragraph:
    print href
    saveFile = open('wpnewspaper_url_collection.txt','a')
    saveFile.write(href.text.encode('utf-8'))
    saveFile.write('\n')
    saveFile.write('\n')
    saveFile.close()
```

This is what i get, of course, this is just a part of my result:

```
<div class="pb-feed-headline"><h3><a href="http://www.washingtonpost.com/world/middle_east/turkey-seeks-behind-scene-role-in-nato-coalition/2014/09/14/4e124944-3beb-11e4-a430-b82a3e67b762_story.html">Turkey seeks behind-scene role in NATO coalition</a></h3></div>
```

But i just want to save the url i.e.

```
http://www.washingtonpost.com/world/middle_east/turkey-seeks-behind-scene-role-in-nato-coalition/2014/09/14/4e124944-3beb-11e4-a430-b82a3e67b762_story.html
```

to the text file.

Comment: sorry i dint have text in my code, its just saveFile.write(hreft.encode('utf-8'))

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are not getting to the actual links. Also, instead of opening the file multiple times in a loop, open it before, and write the link on every iteration and use [`with` context manager](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) to work with a file - it would care about closing it for you.

To get the actual links, I'd use a `div.pb-feed-headline a` [`CSS Selector`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors), which would match every link anywhere inside the `div` with class `pb-feed-headline`.

```
from cookielib import CookieJar
import urllib2

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


cj = CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))

text_file = "http://www.washingtonpost.com/newssearch/search.html?st=turkey&submit=Submit"
soup = BeautifulSoup(opener.open(text_file))

links = soup.select('div.pb-feed-headline a')
with open('wpnewspaper_url_collection.txt', 'w') as f:
    for link in links:
        f.write(link.get('href') + '\n')
```

As a result, in `wpnewspaper_url_collection.txt` you would get:

```
http://www.washingtonpost.com/world/middle_east/turkey-seeks-behind-scene-role-in-nato-coalition/2014/09/14/4e124944-3beb-11e4-a430-b82a3e67b762_story.html
http://www.washingtonpost.com/world/middle_east/turkey-could-accept-muslim-brotherhood-leaders/2014/09/16/7653dc0c-3d6b-11e4-a430-b82a3e67b762_story.html
http://www.washingtonpost.com/world/middle_east/us-expands-aid-funding-for-refugee-crisis-in-syria/2014/09/12/97282b20-3a6b-11e4-8601-97ba88884ffd_story.html
http://www.washingtonpost.com/world/middle_east/hagel-visits-turkey-in-bid-to-strategize-over-coordinated-campaign-against-islamic-state/2014/09/08/6913803e-377f-11e4-9c9f-ebb47272e40e_story.html
http://www.washingtonpost.com/49-reasons-why-turkey-doesnt-want-to-fight-the-islamic-state/2014/09/12/b581f8bb-bbd9-44de-8788-9a09bfd0b3f0_story.html
http://www.washingtonpost.com/world/middle_east/cobbling-coalition-for-iraq-syria-no-easy-task/2014/09/12/11f964c4-3af1-11e4-a023-1d61f7f31a05_story.html
http://www.washingtonpost.com/world/middle_east/us-turkey-mull-strategy-against-islamic-militants/2014/09/12/6479a9bc-3a78-11e4-a023-1d61f7f31a05_story.html
http://www.washingtonpost.com/world/middle_east/cobbling-coalition-for-iraq-syria-no-easy-task/2014/09/12/3c9e50be-3ab9-11e4-a023-1d61f7f31a05_story.html
http://www.washingtonpost.com/world/middle_east/arab-allies-pledge-to-fight-islamic-state-group/2014/09/11/c97927fe-3a2b-11e4-a023-1d61f7f31a05_story.html
http://www.washingtonpost.com/national/wild-turkey-maker-reaches-60th-year-in-business/2014/09/10/8ca01c46-38de-11e4-a023-1d61f7f31a05_story.html
```

Comment: @ alecxe , Thank you so much, it really worked.. appreaciate your help.. I just have one more question , if it is okay for you.. can I get the whole list of url's from all the pages with the keyword turkey from washington post?